# php support for mongoDB

Tags: docker

I am using this image that is working as expected.

https://hub.docker.com/r/clue/adminer/

The only problem is that it does not has php extensions required to connect MongoDB or Oracle...

```
Oracle
None of the supported PHP extensions (OCI8, PDO_OCI) are available.

MongoDB
None of the supported PHP extensions (mongo) are available.
```

Is there an image that includes support for these 2 database?

---

Edit:
I can use another container for Oracle and mongodb like this. But then this container does not support mssql and postgresql.
I am looking for all DB support in a single image.

```
wget http://www.adminer.org/latest.php -O /tmp/index.php

docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /tmp/:/app lukaszkinder/apache-php-oci8-pdo_oci
```

And mongoDB can be connected using this.

```
docker run -d -p 8070:80 -v /tmp:/var/www/html ishiidaichi/apache-php-mongo-phalcon
```

---

Edit 2: 
The dockerfile for oracle is available here.

https://github.com/davidgaya/docker-apache-php-oci/blob/master/Dockerfile

But I am not sure how to merge these 2 docker files.

Answer (score 4):

You could build you own image, using a Dockerfile.

There are two ways :

- Take the [current image Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/clue/adminer/~/dockerfile/) and add what you need. If you do this way, you can delete the unused packages too.
- Create a new one, and just specify that your image is based on the current one, using `FROM` keyword.

Comment: Can you specify a base image which will be work for Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to create your own docker image. It is probably rare you find a ready to go image in the Internet that perfectly fits your requirements.

From my point of view, the best approach would start by creating a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) using your prefered base image (i.e one of those you mentioned). Then add to it the rest of the requirements you need.

Additionally, you can open your own Docker repository in Dockerhub and manage your images from there.

Comment: Can you specify a base image which will be work for Mac?